# Refresh datatable in client side filtering + emberjs + datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, datatable

I am using EmberJs(1.7.0 beta) and jquery.datatables(1.10) in my Rails 4 application. I have a functionality where the list is populated using ember and the table is loaded using datatables. I have a filter functionality where the user types the search string and the table has to be refreshed. Except for the first time when the data is loaded from server, there is no other server interaction.

the router.js.coffee code

```
App.Router.map ->                                                                                                                                       
  @resource 'portfolios', ->
    @route 'edit', {path: '/:id/edit'}
    @route 'show', {path: '/:id'}
```

the index route code

```
App.PortfoliosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend                                                                                               
  model: (params) ->
    @get('store').findAll 'portfolio'

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'data', model
```

the index controller code(i am using query params: emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/)

```
App.PortfoliosIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(                                                                               
  queryParams: ['search_string']
  search_string: null

  filteredPortfolios: (->
    search_string = @get("search_string")
    results = @get('data')

    ### 
    the search string is entered in a input box and on submitting the search form the url is modified as below. ember picks up the changes string and filters the records
    http://localhost:3000/#/portfolios?search_string=random
    ###
    if search_string
      results = results.filter((portfolio) ->
        portfolio.get('portfolio_name').toLowerCase().indexOf(search_string.toLowerCase()) > -1
    )
    results
  ).property('content', 'search_string') 
)
```

the view where the data is rendered

```
<div class="row">                                                                                                                                       
  <h1 class="page-header">Portfolios</h1>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {{#if search_string}}
      {{view App.DataTableView valueBinding="filteredPortfolios"}}
    {{else}}
      {{view App.DataTableView valueBinding="data"}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</div>
```

the view code where the datatable is initialized

```
App.DataTableView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'table'
  classNames: ['dataTable', 'stripe']

  didInsertElement: ->
    if this.get('value')
      data = this.get('value').getEach('data')

    this.$().dataTable
      sDom: '<"col-md-12"<"panel panel-default"t>><"col-md-12"p>'
      iDisplayLength: 25
      sPaginationType: 'simple'
      aaData: data
      aoColumns: [
        {sTitle: 'Id', mData: 'id'},
        {
          sTitle: 'Portfolio Name'
          mData: 'portfolio_name'
          mRender: (data, type, full) ->
            "<a href='#/portfolios/#{full.id}'>#{data}</a>"
        },
        {sTitle: 'Related Name', mData: 'acquisition_name'}
      ]
```

When the page is loaded, the list is displayed. When i enter the search query, the filtering takes place and the filtered data is displayed. When i CHANGE the search query, the filtering occurs but the filtered data is NOT rendered. If i send the search query as an empty string '/#/member_credit_portfolios?search_string=', the entire list is displayed again.

I verfied the resulting data in each case and the data does get filtered and displayed if i dont use the App.DataTableView and just use nornal ul/li to list the data. So the problem does occur at datatables level. How do i solve the above problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ember + DataTables and recently struggled with this same issue.  The root problem is that when you pass in your `data` to `aaData`, you lose Ember's magical two-way binding.  This makes sense, right? After all, why should DataTables be aware of Ember's two-way bindings?

The solution I used is somewhat inelegant but gets the job done.  DataTables can take in its data either through the DOM (i.e. you actually output a full `<table>` data and all with HandleBars and then call `$('#myTable').DataTable()` on that table), through Javascript (as you're doing by passing to the `aaData` property) or through AJAX. See http://www.datatables.net/manual/data#Data-sources.

The only way I found to get the two-way binding was to use the DOM.  This way, HandleBars is always updating my table data for me, and DataTables will simply render those changes.

If you must use javascript, then you effectively have to hand-roll your own two-way binding by detecting changes in the data, and then getting DataTables to manually update the data.  This works great in theory, but I ran into the issue that converting from a rich Ember Data `DS.Model` (rich meaning it has multiple levels of relationships) to the corresponding JSON turned out to be surprisingly tricky.

All of this boils down to the following options:

**Option 1: Use the DOM**

Output your data in a `<table>` in Handlebars and then use DataTables.

**Option 2: Dynamically pass in the data via Javascript and manually handle data updates**

What you do now, except that you'll have to manually check for updates to the data, and then use the DataTables API to clear the table and update it, paying special attention to rich JSON objects.  Consider writing special APIs in your backend to return DataTables-formatted JSON versus just Ember Data JSON, clearly not ideal, but easier to manage.

I'm still establishing DataTables patterns for large datasets in my Ember app, too, so will be interested to hear how you ultimately resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood from your question :

1. you can load the page, with an optional parameter `search_string` which should filter the initially displayed results,
2. whatever the content of the initial `search_string` is, you want to preserve the "dynamic filtering" option of your datatable, without sending any further query to the server.

If this is the behaviour you want :

- you need to have the server send all the data (no filtering on the server side)
- you need to drop the `{{#if search_string}}` bloc in the handlebars template - just render the whole table :

  ```
  {{view App.DataTableView valueBinding="data"}}
  ```
- you just need to set the initial value of the [`search.search`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/search.search) option (or the [`oSearch.sSearch`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#oSearch) option if you are using the 1.9 flavored API), on the client side, when initializing your datatable
- check the datatable API and examples if you want a customized filtering function